# Get length of String via its ID (R.id. )

Tags: android, database, string, android-listview, int

I have in my application a listview displaying elements from a database. Every elements of the listview displays some content from my database elements, as well as a button.

Later, I will make this button open the dial menu of the phone and call a number when clicked. What I want now is to display this button only when the length of an element from my database associated to the listview is equal to 7. My problem is to get the length of this string as it's called from my database using the id of the object.

Here is my code, the element I would like to check the length is "telephone" with R.id.telephone, it is called from the database and then sent to another activity :

```
private void displayListView() {

    // getExtra
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String title = bundle.getString("title", "Choose here :");
    String inInterval = bundle.getString("inInterval");
    Log.d(TAG, "inInterval = " + inInterval);

    poititle.setText(title);

    // put the results of the method in a cursor
    Cursor c = dbHelper.findPoiInTable(inInterval);
    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.COL_NAME,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_STREET, DatabaseAdapter.COL_WEBSITE,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_TELEPHONE, DatabaseAdapter.COL_REMARKS,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_PRICE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.street, R.id.website,
            R.id.telephone, R.id.remarks, R.id.price };
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.poi_info, c,
            columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poilistview);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        // Comportement des éléments de la listview
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    POIActivity.class);

            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String website = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.website))
                    .getText().toString();
            String telephone = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.telephone)).getText().toString();
            String remarks = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remarks))
                    .getText().toString();
            String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price))
                    .getText().toString();
            // i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, name) ;
            i.putExtra(ID_NAME, name);
            i.putExtra(ID_WEBSITE, website);
            i.putExtra(ID_TELEPHONE, telephone);
            i.putExtra(ID_REMARKS, remarks);
            i.putExtra(ID_PRICE, price);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }); }
```

Here is what I tried : I created a method callbuttonManagement() in the same activity that I called from my diplsayListView() method whose code is above, and that I define this way :

```
public void callbuttonManagement() {

    int countTelephone = ID_TELEPHONE.length();
    if (countTelephone == 7)
    {
        callButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        callButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}
```

It crashes my app and logcat indicates a nullpointerexception. Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Comment: where is that ID_TELEPHONE from?

Comment: is callbuttonManagement in activity POIActivity?

Comment: The ID_TELEPHONE is defined in the layout organizing the elements of the list, like this : <TextView
        android:id="@+id/telephone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" /> I did this just because I needed to define it somewhere or it wouldn't work.

Comment: I need to know in which activity is callbuttonManagement defined.

Comment: your code is a bit too odd. Anyways post the logcat, and say where exactly is it throwing the NPE

Comment: callButtonManagement is in the same activity, right under displayListView. They both are in the activity called "ResultListViewActivity" displaying the listview with content inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
class member boolean mShowButton;
String telephone = ((TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.telephone)).getText().toString();

if (telephone.length() == 7)
{
     mShowButton = true:
}

public void callbuttonManagement() {


if (mShowButton)
{
    callButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{
    callButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


}
```